# Problem setting desktop wallpaper using SystemParametersInfo Function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am just learning C++ and am trying to write a small program to change the desktop wallpaper. Using the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947), I wrote this program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

void main(){

    BOOL success = SystemParametersInfo(
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,   //iuAction
    0,                      //uiParam
    "C:\\test.jpg",         //pvParam
    SPIF_SENDCHANGE         //fWinIni
    );
    if (success){
        printf("Success!\n");
    }else
        printf("Failure =(\n");
}
```

The program always fails when I try to specify a file path for pvParam. It will correctly clear the wallpaper if I set pvParam to "". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
-Abhorsen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It addition to Dennis' comment about JPEG files, it is also important whether or not you compile with UNICODE in effect.  If you do then you'll have to specify the file as L"C:\test.jpg".  Note the L in front of the string, that makes it a wide string.  Or use SystemParametersInfoA(), note the A (but it's archaic).

Comment: Specifying the file as L"C:\\test.jpg" worked. Can you explain what it means to compile with UNICODE in effect and how I could check to see whether or not I am doing so?

Comment: It is on the General settings page, Character Set setting.

Comment: To add some more background to this answer for future readers, Unicode issues crop up constantly when using windows.h and related. There is more information about unicode here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS version, pvParam might not work.

If you are using Windows XP coupled with a JPEG file you are trying to assign as a wallpaper, notice the comment in the docs:

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows
>   XP/2000: The pvParam parameter cannot
>   specify a .jpg file.